# 403 Error when using nginx to access file other than index.htm

Tags: webserver, nginx

I set up nginx on Ubuntu 12.04 and when remotely accessing a file other than the index.htm/php/html, the server says that access is forbidden. I tried to search for a solution but no luck. Any ideas/hints/solutions???

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the files/directories? `ls -l` will list all the files and their permissions. If the permissions of index.* are the same as the other files then something else is wrong. Let us know if this is the case

Answer (score 1):

403 errors in nginx get thrown when ownership of other files isnt compatible with the user that `nginx` runs as.  Use `ls -l` on the web root folder to find ownership of the files.  Make sure that the group part is www-data.  If its in any user-level folders (such as your home directory), make sure that www-data can read the file directory structure to there.

Without more details, though, I can't explain how to fix this any better...  attaching details about the file structure, where on the drive your files are sitting, etc. may help.

(Source: Me, as I'm on the nginx team)